# inserting connection of DB to Every other forms inside the functions

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
namespace PCJ_System
{
    class DB_CONNECTION
    {

        public SqlConnection getConnection()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = null; ;
            try
            {
                conn = new SqlConnection("data source= DESKTOP-LKEG8FM\\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog= PCJ_DB ; Integrated Security=True;");
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can't Open Connection !" + ex);
            }
            return conn;
        }

    }
}
```

This is my forms code: public partial class Form1 : this below code is working but i typing the sqlconnection again. which should be wrong way of coding.

```
namespace PCJ_System
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
         SqlConnection conn;
        SqlCommand cmd;
      //  SqlDataReader dr;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string str = "server = DESKTOP-LKEG8FM\\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog= PCJ_DB ; Integrated Security=True;";/again and again i am calling the=is to every other forms is it the correct way /
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str); 
          //  DB_CONNECTION x = new DB_CONNECTION();
            conn.Open();
            string GetData = "Select [FC_Rate] from Forcur where FC_TYPE ='" + comboBox1.Text + "' ";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(GetData, conn);
            var returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            textBox1.Text = returnValue.ToString();
            conn.Close();

        }

    }
}
```

How can I call the my `Dbconnection` to every single function.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your Code:

```
string str = "server = DESKTOP-LKEG8FM\\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog= PCJ_DB ;Integrated Security=True;";
/again and again i am calling the=is to every other forms is it the correct way /
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str); 
//  DB_CONNECTION x = new DB_CONNECTION();
conn.Open();
```

With the following:

```
DB_CONNECTION x = new DB_CONNECTION();
SqlConnection conn = x.getConnection();
```

Comment: one more thing,  i dont need to include the conn.Open in the statement

Comment: but conn.Close(); this is neccessary right when the fuction end

Answer (score 0):

One way that you could do to avoid repeating your code is create `BaseForm` and put you general codes in it then All your forms should Inherit `BaseForm`

```
public abstract class BaseForm:Form{
        public SqlConnection getConnection()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = null; ;
            try
            {
                conn = new SqlConnection("data source= DESKTOP-LKEG8FM\\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog= PCJ_DB ; Integrated Security=True;");
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can't Open Connection !" + ex);
            }
            return conn;
        }
}
```

and your Form should change like this :

```
public partial class Form1 : BaseForm
{
    SqlCommand cmd;
  //  SqlDataReader dr;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = "server = DESKTOP-LKEG8FM\\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog= PCJ_DB ; Integrated Security=True;";/again and again i am calling the=is to every other forms is it the correct way /


        string GetData = "Select [FC_Rate] from Forcur where FC_TYPE ='" + comboBox1.Text + "' ";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(GetData, getConnection());
        var returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        textBox1.Text = returnValue.ToString();
        conn.Close();

    }

}
```